# Spin of 2 oppositely charged fused point charges

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, charge, torque, point-particles

If i fused 2 point particles (with opposite charges) together, would it be possible to change the magnitude of this object's spin by applying a torque on it?

Also, if they are joined together, wouldn't they be classified as a non-elementary particle and therefore their spin be a non-intrinsic property?

Basically, what i am asking is if the angular momentum of **2 fused point particles** can be changed by applying a torque.

Comment: Spin is intrinsic angular momentum. Can't change that.

Comment: But with 2 merged particles. Wouldn't that be classified as a non-elementary particle then?

Comment: Yes. But still you have to use angular momentum algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spins add such that the composite of particles with spins $S_1$ and $S_2$ can have spin between $|S_1 - S_2|$ and $S_1 + S_2$. In the simplest non-trivial case, two spin $\frac 1 2$ particles can have total spin $0$ or $1$, as you can check by applying the operator $\hat{S}^2 = (\hat{\mathbf S}_1 + \hat{\mathbf S}_2)^2$ to the states $\lvert\uparrow \uparrow\rangle - \vert\uparrow \downarrow\rangle $ for spin 0, and $\lvert\uparrow \downarrow\rangle + \lvert\downarrow\uparrow\rangle, \uparrow\uparrow\rangle + \lvert\downarrow\downarrow\rangle, \lvert \downarrow \uparrow \rangle + \lvert \uparrow\downarrow\rangle$ for spin 1.

Transitions between different $S^2$ happen all the time in composite systems such as atoms, molecules, and atomic nuclei. For example, the ground state of the helium atom is spin 0 but its first excited state is spin 1. If you look at a [table of isotopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_sodium#List_of_isotopes) for a given element, you can see that there are often isomers that have the same composition but differ in energy, i.e., one is an excited state, and also differ in spin.

As for the second part of your question, in the common conception of what it means to be an elementary particle -- Wigner's classification -- an elementary particle corresponds to an irreducible representation, i.e., $S^2$ takes only one value.

Comment: But if you applied a torque to those fused particles, would the spin of it increase?

Comment: @HamiHashmi, spin (intrinsic angular momentum) is related to the transformation properties of the particle under a rotation of coordinates.  For example, rotating the coordinate system by 1 full rotation leaves a vector unchanged and so vector particles, e.g., photons, are spin 1.  Why would you think applying a torque  has anything at all to do with spin?

Comment: well because torque is used to change angular momentum

Comment: @HamiHashmi Because spin is quantized, I don't know if it's very useful to think in terms of torque at the level of atoms and such. We rather talk about transitions and (gamma) decay). But yes, such processes can and do change $S^2$ all the time. As for torque, by the Ehrenfest theorem, in a quantum system the *expectation values* of observables obey classical equations. So, if you write down the equation for the expectation value of the spin, you can call the right-hand side the torque.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri You can't change the value of $S^2$ for a given species of particle, but you can make a *composite system* transition from, say, a singlet state to a triplet state ($S^2 = 0 \to S^2 = 2$). If you consider a spin polarized orthohelium gas and let it cool to the ground state, the photon gas carries off angular momentum and you could consider this a torque on the helium.

Comment: But with black holes, the singularity can gain angular momentum if the black hole starts accreting gas. Isnt that torque?